# How to fix the Typescript error where the reading is null?

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, mapping, undefined-behavior

I am trying to render out an array but it keeps giving me the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')".

Companies is an array of objects. The toggle button allows user to toggle between displaying information and the input field. But now I could not even load the component as the page would not map out either one.

```js
<div className="w-work">
  {companies.map((company, index) => {
    return toggle ? (
      <div className="w-workplace" key={index}>
        {company.place}
        <br />
        {company.description}
        <br />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className="w-educationplace" key={index}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="place"
          placeholder="Name"
          value={company.place}
          onChange={(event) => updateWork(index, "place", event.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="description"
          placeholder="DESCRIPTION"
          value={company.description}
          onChange={(event) =>
            updateWork(index, "description", event.target.value)
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>;
```

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Is this a `runtime error` or the `IDE typescript is complaining?` . What is the type of `companies`, can you debug to see its value before performing a map. Another alternative is to use `console.log(`companies`,companies)` somewhere before the rendering

Comment: Hi, so i did this on line 2 **{companies && companies.map((company, index) => {** and now the page loads. However, when I toggle, the input field doesnt work.

Comment: The array is empty as of now.

Comment: Either debug and see what value the variable `companies` is before rendering or put `console.log("companies", companies)` just before rendering. With provided details it seems its value is null or undefined